# Three.js animation mixer not playing?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, three.js, 3d

Ok I have an fbx successfully loaded into Three.js exported from blender with all animation boxes checked. Ive tried all export settings from blender so that's not it.

This is how I bring the model in, and I am able to accurately determine whether the fbx has animations or not:

```
var geoFromScene = new THREE.Geometry();
var FBXLoader = require('three-fbx-loader');
var loader = new FBXLoader();
                loader.load(string, function ( object ) {

                    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                        if ( child.isMesh ) {
                            child.castShadow = true;
                            child.receiveShadow = true;

              geoFromScene = (new THREE.Geometry()).fromBufferGeometry(child.geometry);

                        }


                    } );

          var theModel = new THREE.Mesh();
          theModel.geometry = geoFromScene;
          theModel.material = material;
          theModel.position.set(5,5,-8);
          //theModel.rotation.set(new THREE.Vector3( 0, MATH.pi/2, 0));
          theModel.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
                    localThis.scene.add(theModel);

          localThis.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(theModel);

          if(theModel.animations[0])
          {
            var action = localThis.mixer.clipAction(theModel.animations[0]);
                    action.play();
          } else {
            console.log("No animations");
          }

                } );
```

In update (which does work, because I can print the animation.time):

```
this.mixer.update(this.clock.getDelta());
```

And yet the model is just static. Whats wrong here?

UPDATE:

code from example copy pasted-

```
var geoFromScene = new THREE.Geometry();
var FBXLoader = require('three-fbx-loader');
var loader = new FBXLoader();
loader.load( string, function ( object ) {
                    localThis.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( object );
                    var action = localThis.mixer.clipAction( object.animations[ 0 ] );
                    action.play();

                    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                        if ( child.isMesh ) {
                            child.castShadow = true;
                            child.receiveShadow = true;
                        }
                    } );

          object.position.set(5,5,-8)
          object.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
                    localThis.scene.add( object );


                } );
```

in animate-

```
this.mixer.update(this.clock.getDelta());
```

All I get is the model armature it seems -

[image]

New approach:

```
var FBXLoader = require('wge-three-fbx-loader'); //https://www.npmjs.com/package/wge-three-fbx-loader
var loader = new FBXLoader();
loader.load( string, function ( object ) {
```

Comment: Why do you convert the loaded geometry to `THREE.Geometry`? Besides, it should not be necessary to create a custom mesh (if anything, you would have to create an instance of `THREE.SkinnedMesh`). Anyway, it's best to stick to the official example. Please write your code similar to https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_fbx

Comment: @Mugen87 ok, Ive copied the example code verbatim AND am using their model - still no animations. Ive updated my question